# getchar() working abnormally

Tags: c, stdin, getchar

I am trying to read characters one at a time and convert them to int in a cumulative manner. If the user enters a character other than a number i start the whole process all over again.
When i run this code, the code below `getchar()` gets executed only after i press the enter key instead of executing with every key press. In brief, instead of taking one character at a time, it takes a string terminated with enter as input and then reads one character at a time from the input string and executes the while loop.
I am pretty sure it has something to do with the `\n` in the printf statements.
My c code:

```
    char* input=malloc(0);
    char c; 
    int count=0;
    int a;
    int b;  
    errno=0;
    printf("\nEnter two numbers a and b\n");

    while(1){
        count++;
        printf(":Count:%d",count);
        c=getchar();
        printf("\n::%c::\n",c);
        if(c=='\n')
            break;
        input=realloc(input,count);
        input[count-1]=c;
        errno=0;
        a=strtol(input,NULL,10);
        printf("\nNUMber::%d\n",a);
        if (errno == ERANGE && (a == LONG_MAX || a == LONG_MIN)){
            printf("\nLets start over again and please try entering numbers only\n");
            count=0;
            input=realloc(input,0);     
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because of the fact that `getchar()` is terminal io settings dependent. Since most terminals have line buffering enabled, it waits until you press enter. Using `termios.h`, you can disable that. `getch()` is windows-only. Also, why `realloc(<x>, 0)`? Why not just `free()`?. Also, `malloc(0)` is undefined behaviour. It can return NULL, or SEGFAULT.

Comment: "getch() working abnormally" - I doubt. A decent standard library implementation hardly has bugs.

Comment: mybad read the title again..its getchar()

Comment: malloc(0) does no harm at all.

Comment: @H2CO3 everything ever programmed has bugs.

Comment: @thunderbird I didn't write "it doesn't have bugs". Make the distinction. The world is not black and white.

Comment: `malloc(0)` does no harm but passing the returned pointer (or NULL) to `strtol` (as parameter `input`) does

Comment: @msam its just my style of coding..whenever i use realloc on a variable I initialize it with malloc(0)..i cant see how its wrong?

Comment: if `count` is 0 your `realloc` will free `input`, and set input to either NULL or a freeable but undeferencable pointer which you then pass to `strtol`

Comment: @msam count is never zero...count++ is at the very beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the fact that `getchar()` is terminal io settings dependent. Since most terminals have line buffering enabled, it waits until you press enter. Using `termios.h`, you can disable that. `getch()` is windows-only.

Here is some code to do what `getch()` does in Linux.

```
#include <termios.h>

char getch(void) {
    /* get original settings */
    struct termios new, old;
    tcgetattr(0, &old);
    new = old;

    /* set new settings and flush out terminal */
    new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &new);

    /* get char and reset terminal */
    char ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &old);

    return ch;
}
```

Also, why `realloc(blah, 0)`? Why not just `free(blah)`?. 
Also, `malloc(0)` is undefined behaviour. It can return NULL or give a unique pointer. Same with `realloc(blah, 0)`.

Comment: But `free(NULL)` is valid and allowed.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char getch()
{
char c; // This function should return the keystroke

system("stty raw");    // Raw input - wait for only a single keystroke
system("stty -echo");  // Echo off

c = getchar();

system("stty cooked"); // Cooked input - reset
system("stty echo");   // Echo on - Reset

return c;
}
```

Comment: `system()` is unsafe. What if someone replaces the `stty` binary with something evil? Or they just put an evil binary in your current directory, and changed your path to `.:/bin:/usr/bin`?